# Generating charts with only users patients, not entire patient db. Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chartkick

I'm using ChartKicks to create charts in rails. Currently the charts are being generated by using every in the database. How can I get this to be just the current users patients. I'm using the clearance gem, so the current user.

Controller that renders report page

```
 def report 
    render 'patients/report'
  end

def create
    @patient = current_user.patients.build(patient_params)

    if @patient.save
      redirect_to patient_path(@patient), notice: "Patient Added"
    else
      @errors = @patient.errors.full_messages
      render :new
    end
  end
```

Page which generates report

```
<div class="row charts">
        <div class="col-md-6" id="patients-illness">
            <%= pie_chart Patient.group(:ailment).count %>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why using Patient.group(:ailment).count, why not current_user.patients.group(:ailment).count ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

```
current_user.patients.group(:ailment).count
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks so much